# Can't Release NSFetchedResultsController in dealloc

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, release-management, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two UITableViewControllers with a fairly simple ui flow. One UITableViewController loads another UITableViewController when you select an item in the first UITableViewController.

---

(UITableViewController) List of Stories -> Select a Story -> (UITableViewController) List of Sentences

---

In the second UITableViewController (MakeSentenceDetailViewController) I can't release my     NSFetchedResultsController without causing an error (shown with Zombies set to on):

> -[NSFetchRequest release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5b370f0

The retain count of the NSFetchedResultsController stays at 1 but when I try to release it in dealloc I get a crash.

The code, especially in regards to the NSFetchedResultsController is the same in both tableviews, but in the MakeSentenceDetailViewController I can't release this NSFetchedResults Controller with a crash - giving me a leak.

How can I safely release my NSFetchedResultsController? Why does it work fine in the parent (first) tableviewcontroller - but not in the second?

I can provide code for the first UITableViewController but in regards to NSFetchedResultsController it's declared and used in much the same way.

MakeSentenceTableViewController.h:

```
@interface MakeSentenceTableViewController : UITableViewController {
NSManagedObjectContext  *managedObjectContext;  
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)  Story *story;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@end
```

MakeSentenceTableViewController.m (relevant code with NSFetchedResultsController):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
 { 
 managedObjectContext = [(MyAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
 NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
 }
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sentence" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
  [request setEntity:entity];
  //sorting stuff:
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order" ascending: YES];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil];
  [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
  //[request setFetchBatchSize:FETCH_BATCH_SIZE];
  [sortDescriptors release];
  [sortDescriptor release];
  fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
    initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
    sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
  [request release];
  NSError *error;
  [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
  NSLog(@"FetchedResultsController: %@", fetchedResultsController);
  NSLog(@"fetchedResultsController RetainCount at viewDidLoad: %d", [fetchedResultsController retainCount]);
 }

 - (void)dealloc {

  //Gotta figure out why I can't release this:
  [fetchedResultsController release]; //Crash! Burn! 
  NSLog(@"fetchedResultsController RetainCount at dealloc: %d", [fetchedResultsController retainCount]);
  [managedObjectContext release];
  [super dealloc];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
// ...snip...
[request release];
```

You're releasing an object that you've relinquished ownership of (with `-autorelease`). You don't get an error at the point of the other release because the NSFetchedResultsController is also retaining the fetch request; thus the controller is the one actually causing the crash when it releases the last reference to the fetch request.

Comment: Thankyou - that fixes the problem, but it also creates (or reveals) another. Now every third time (like clockwork) that I go into the MakeSentenceViewController (switching between TableViewControllers using the navigation controller) I crash on this line of code: managedObjectContext = [(MyAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; Can you see any obvious connection? It make be outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Depends on exactly how it's crashing.

Comment: Allright, I'd do some extra debugging over the next week or so - and post the solution here if I find it, if I can't I'll create a new Question. Thanks heaps for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-releasing the NSFetchRequest

You autorelease it here:

```
   NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
```

then release it again later:

```
  [request release];
```

then later when you release the fetchedResultsController, it tries to release that same request again.